# Two lists of coords returning most distinct minimal for one list based on distance function

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I have a list of coords using Tuple, since I don't have access to the Drawing library to use 'Point'.

```
List<Tuple<int,int>> coords = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();
string[] movement = new string[temp.Count];
  for(int i=1000; i<=8000; i=i+2300)
    for(int j=1000; j<=15000; j=j+2000)
      coords.Add(Tuple.Create(j,i));
coords.RemoveAll(x=> 3500>= getDist(0,0,x.Item1,x.Item2) );
coords.RemoveAll(x=> 3500>= getDist(16000,9000,x.Item1,x.Item2) );
```

I have player pieces in a list, two examples below.

```
List<int[]> player = new List<int[]>() {new int[]{0,726,1084,0,0,5},new int[]{2,1481,2208,0,0,-1} };
//piece numb, loc_X, loc_Y, teamID, state, value
```

Turn-based movements must be figured, and when the state of a piece indicates scouting, I want to find the most minimal coord-point-set to each scouting piece, without two pieces going to the same set of coords. If I try to use a foreach loop like:

```
foreach(var myBust in temp) {
  int minDist = coords.Select(x => getDist( x.Item1,x.Item2,myBust[1],myBust[2]) ).OrderBy(x => x).Distinct().First();
  coords.RemoveAll(x => getDist(16000,9000,x.Item1,x.Item2) == minDist); }
```

then I fall into an issue that the first piece configured may not be the closest to a point-set as compared to another scouting piece, which is why the foreach loop doesn't work or me. Therefore I want some type of linq/lambda statement that can return the said "Distinct" minimal coord-point in the coord list in comparison (by getDist and Min) to all the player pieces.

```
//Not sure why this doesn't give me what I am looking for 
int minDist= coords.Zip(player, (x,y) => getDist(x.Item1,x.Item2,y[1],y[2])).Min();
```

My dist method.

```
static int getDist(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{    return Convert.ToInt32( Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x1-x2,2) + Math.Pow(y1-y2,2) );}
```

So for an answer I am looking for a way to run a function on two lists, which runs a function (but doesn't aggregate anything together), and can return whatever I want from one or both of those lists.

Based on the answer from @Jacob I came up with the below so far:

```
string[] movement = new string[player.Count];
List<int[]> temp = player;
while(temp.Any()){
  HashSet<int> dists = new HashSet<int>();
  foreach(var myBust in temp)
  { dists.UnionWith(coords.Select(x => getDist(x.Item1,x.Item2,myBust[1],myBust[2]) ));    }  
  foreach(var myBust in player)
  { if(coords.Exists(x => getDist( x.Item1,x.Item2,myBust[1],myBust[2]) == dists.Min() ) )
    {
        Tuple<int,int> result = coords.FindAll(x => getDist( x.Item1,x.Item2,myBust[1],myBust[2]) == dists.Min() ).First();
        movement[player.IndexOf(myBust)] = "Move " + result.Item1 + " " + result.Item2;
        Console.WriteLine("Player Number "+myBust[0]+" going a dist of "+dists.Min()+" to coords "+result.Item1+","+result.Item2);
        coords.Remove(result);
        temp.Remove(myBust);
    }    
  }
}
```

This gives the correct output of "Player Number 2 going a dist of 1871 to coords 3000,3300".
That is at least the first iteration through but then throws the error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."
Any suggestions or modifications would be appreciated.

Comment: You should reformulate your question because it's not entirely clear :)

Comment: Side note: it feels like `int[]` should be some sort of class with properties...

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to stop using arrays to store aggregated data. Declare a user-defined type (i.e. a `class`) with the appropriate properties to store the values you want (e.g. `X` and `Y`). The second thing you need to do is improve the question so we can understand what you mean. Start by providing a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do, and explain exactly what that code does and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: To elaborate on the user-defined types: you may (will probably) find that it makes sense to create or use a built-in `Point` or similar type just for `X` and `Y`, and then include that type in your `Player` type, along with whatever other player data you want.

Comment: Not sure what isn't clear, but as to making a class to store player information is a possibility, but even so then you would have a list of players with current coords on a grid map. I am trying to get a turn-based list of movement coords, were none of the coords are duplicated between players (or scouts). I had a simple solution but I found that the first myBust could hijack the minDist that another scout was already going, when it's job function changed to scout; even if the following scout was closer.

Comment: As stated new, as such just now hearing of `Point` @PeterDuniho. Recently dealt with Tuples as well, for given "existing" nodes in a grid. Still unsure why my Zip usage does not return the actual MIN of two lists of grid sets? So even using a Point setup for a list of players how do you compare to easily through linq to a list of defined coords and a distance function?

Comment: _"Not sure what isn't clear"_ -- well, this for starters: _"I found that the first myBust could hijack the minDist that another scout was already going, when it's job function changed to scout; even if the following scout was closer"_. There is zero context that would allow any of us to understand what any of that meant. Your question is similarly opaque.

Comment: My suggestion to use complex types instead of arrays was as much intended as a way for you to present your question more clearly, as it was as an aid to your own coding practices. Named types can make code a lot more readable, and readable code can allow others to comprehend a question when the non-code parts of the question are deficient in clarity.

Comment: I tried clarifying a little more, I hope that helps. Once I get the most minimal distance of any player piece to a coord point, I can remove that from the coord list easy enough, and then I would just have to interiate over what ever linq function provides the next player/coordPoint.Min() set.

Comment: _"Trying to clarify, with a foreach loop, that starts with the player piece indexed at 0 can grab the first set of coords that is its minDist to, and therefore be given that as movement instructions."_ - what? You really need to re-read your question and try to make it clear and concise. (And I did just pick this one sentence almost at random. The others aren't terribly clear to me either.)

Comment: I again edited my post, please let me know if it is still "vague".

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want each player piece to get its closest coordinates from a set of coordinates, and you also want each player piece to not share a coordinate. There is probably not a simple one-liner for that without avoiding terrible algorithmic complexity. You have two major concerns; finding the closest coordinates and eliminating previously-used coordinates or players.

So let's use this algorithm:

1. Create a list of player/coordinate pairs, ordered by distance.
2. Create an empty set of players & coordinates that have already been used.
3. Loop through the player/coordinate pairs. If the pair is for a player and coordinate that hasn't been assigned, use that point, since it should be the shortest, then mark the player & coordinate as assigned.

As stated by others, this code would be clearer if you used more descriptive objects instead of arrays, but let's stick with what we have.

Here's an attempt at this:

```
var players = new List<int[]>() { new int[] { 0, 726, 1084, 0, 0, 5 }, new int[] { 2, 1481, 2208, 0, 0, -1 } };
List<int[]> coords = new List<int[]>();
for (int i = 1000; i <= 8000; i = i + 2300)
    for (int j = 1000; j <= 15000; j = j + 2000)
        coords.Add(new int[2] { j, i });

coords.RemoveAll(x => 3500 >= getDist(0, 0, x[0], x[1]));
coords.RemoveAll(x => 3500 >= getDist(16000, 9000, x[0], x[1]));

var closestPoints =
    from playerIdx in Enumerable.Range(0, players.Count())
    let player = players[playerIdx]
    from coordIdx in Enumerable.Range(0, coords.Count())
    let theseCoords = coords[coordIdx]
    orderby getDist(theseCoords[0], theseCoords[1], player[1], player[2])
    select new { playerIdx, coordIdx };

var playerCoords = new Dictionary<int, int>();
var usedPlayers = new HashSet<int>();
var usedCoords = new HashSet<int>();
foreach (var pairing in closestPoints)
{
    if (!usedPlayers.Contains(pairing.playerIdx)
        && !usedCoords.Contains(pairing.coordIdx))
    {
        playerCoords[pairing.playerIdx] = pairing.coordIdx;
        usedPlayers.Add(pairing.playerIdx);
        usedCoords.Add(pairing.coordIdx);
    }
}

// Result is in playerCoords as { 0: 0, 1: 6 }
```

If you have a large number of players or coordinates, this still isn't terribly efficient, since you're computing the distance for every single player/coordinate pairing. You may want to find a shortcut to avoid computing some of these. See [Closest Pair: A Divide-and-Conquer approach](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~cs251/ClosestPair/ClosestPairDQ.html) for ideas there.

Comment: As I understand it, from what I have read, Enumerable.Range is very process intensive so I previously stayed away from that coding. I do like HashSet since it has faster iteration times, as well never lets you add dups. But based on what you said, I imagine creating a temp HashSet dists of all piece/coords sets, taking the Min() then removing the piece/coord set that equals that and run through that process again until there are no more pieces that need scouting instructions.

Comment: `Enumerable.Range` is not process intensive AFAIK; would be interested where you're getting that information. It's certainly not as efficient as a regular loop, of course.

Comment: Well I am still an amateur and if I am wrong on that point, that is another thing I will look into at some other point.

Comment: Ok well tried this code on csharppad.com and unsure what the result is really giving me.

Comment: Keys = index of player, Values = index of coordinates.

Comment: Jacob This question was during a learning process, but has been of no help to anyone else, and therefore I would like to remove it from SO. To do that though it can have no answers. So I was wondering if you can delete your answer to where I can then remove this from SO?